# AnalysisException: u'Cannot resolve column name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark. I had parsed csv file into a dataframe. I am not able to select certain columns from the data frame. Following is the schema of my table:
root

```
 |-- _c0: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- track_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- size_bytes: long (nullable = true)
 |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- rating_count_tot: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- rating_count_ver: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- user_rating: double (nullable = true)
 |-- user_rating_ver: double (nullable = true)
 |-- ver: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cont_rating: string (nullable = true)
 |-- prime_genre: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sup_devices.num: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ipadSc_urls.num: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- lang.num: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- vpp_lic: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Gigabytes: double (nullable = true)
```

While I am able to select some of the columns but when I am trying to select a column "ipadSc_urls.num" (one of the columns in the dataframe), I am getting an error.

[image: error description]

Comment: Please don't add errors, code etc. as images, just copy the text here and f. ex. use the code format tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to enclose column name in **backquotes(`)**.

```
my_df.select('`ipadSc_urls.num`').show()
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked, btw can you please tell me he reason  why do i have to do this to specific columns?because some of the columns were working

Comment: @AnujMahajan, if you have special characters like `.` in column names, then only we need to enclose columns in **back quotes(`)**

Comment: try with `my_df.columns` without parentheses!